# How to preserve plot sizes when stacking with common x-axes in ggarrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to stack plots with common x- and y-axes in ggplot. What I want to do is have only the bottom plot show the x-axis labels and titles. But I've never been able to figure out how to do this cleanly in ggplot2 without having the bottom plot be squished by carrying the virtue of the x-axis labels/title. There *must* be an easy way to do this- everyone wants to stack graphs, right?!

I'm currently trying with ggarrange. Example code below. Note that the bottom plot gets compressed vertically because it has the tick and axis labels. I could just have the top two have white font labels/title, but then there is an unseemly amount of margin space between the three if you use that hack.

I'm definitely open to packages other than gpubr, but I am hoping for something not too elaborate that I can use in subsequent situations, as I'm sure I'll encounter this again...

Help, please!! -Ryan

#

```
require(ggplot2); require(ggpubr)

X=data.frame(seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"),as.Date("2001-12-31"),by='days')); colnames(X)='date'
X$Y1=sample(80:100,size=nrow(X),replace=T)
X$Y2=sample(100:120,size=nrow(X),replace=T)
X$Y3=sample(50:70,size=nrow(X),replace=T)

plot.Y1= ggplot(X, aes(x=date,y=Y1))+
  geom_line()+lims(y=c(50,150))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank())

plot.Y2= ggplot(X, aes(x=date,y=Y2))+
  geom_line()+lims(y=c(50,150))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank())

plot.Y3= ggplot(X, aes(x=date,y=Y3))+
  geom_line()+lims(y=c(50,150))

x11(10,8)

ggarrange(plot.Y1,plot.Y2,plot.Y3,nrow=3,ncol=1)
```

[Bottom plot is squished!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOy1N.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
egg::ggarrange(plot.Y1,plot.Y2,plot.Y3,ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain why this is a correct answer. Visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) if you are unsure what I mean.

Comment: Wow, perfect! And the easy solution I was looking for! I think that there are just too many ggpackages to keep track of out there and sometimes even deep searches can't land on the solution. 

Thanks!!!